# How do I use jest with coffeescript and ES6/ES2015 (e.g. via Babel)?

Tags: coffeescript, ecmascript-6, webpack, jestjs, jest-webpack-alias

My team has been using both coffeescript and ES6/ES2015 (via Babel) in our project. Since the files are ultimately compatible due to Babel, it's been working great. But I can't figure out how we can write a jest test that allows both.

I've found examples of how to use jest with coffee, or ES6 features, but not both:

- [Example with coffeescript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27155661/135101)
- [Another example with coffeescript](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-coffeescript.html#content)
- [Example with Babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870296/how-to-use-jest-with-webpack)
- Somewhere someone suggested to set the preprocessor as `babel-jest`, which works fine for me if I only use it with ES6.

**These all work. But again, I can't figure out how to combine them**

## What I've tried

- I tried my own solution:

  In `package.json` I have:

  ```
  "jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/jest-script-preprocessor",
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dom",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-addons-test-utils",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/fbjs"
    ],
    "testFileExtensions": ["coffee", "cjsx", "js", "jsx"],
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["coffee", "cjsx", "js", "jsx"]
  }
  ```

  In `jest-script-preprocessor.js`, I have:

  ```
  var coffee = require('coffee-react');
  var transform = require('coffee-react-transform');
  var babelJest = require("babel-jest");

  module.exports = {
      process: function(src, path) {
          if (coffee.helpers.isCoffee(path)) {
              console.log(path);
              return coffee.compile(transform(src), {
                  'bare': true
              });
          } else {
              console.log(path);
              return babelJest.process(src, {
                  filename: path,
                  stage: 0
              });
          }
      }
  };
  ```

  If I run a test like `npm test __tests__/sometest.jsx`, it loads the ES6 test file fine. That test file will import the module under test, which is also ES6, and THAT'S where it blows up. It simply says `Unexpected reserved word` as soon as it hits an ES6-only syntax, like `import`, `export`, etc. There is [no additional line information](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/561), but I know it's ES6 that causes the problem because if I change the module under test to be ONLY `export default 'mystring'`, it blows up, and if I change it to non-ES6 syntax like `var q = 5 + 5; module.exports = q;`, it imports the module fine. (Of course, that's not really a testable module, but it doesn't need to be for this proof-of-concept.)

  Note the `console.log()` lines in there. I never see them. So one reason this has been so tricky to track down is I can't put any of my own debug logic in. I'm sure these lines run, because if I throw in some random syntax on those lines, it'll choke. But no console output.
- I've tried [jest-webpack-alias](https://github.com/Ticketmaster/jest-webpack-alias), which is [officially recommended by jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-webpack-integration.html#content), and it sounds great in theory: you use jest with webpack, which then allows you to use whatever preprocessors you've already set up. It gives me the same error of `Unexpected reserved word`. I wrote up [an issue on their github repo](https://github.com/Ticketmaster/jest-webpack-alias/issues/13).

## Notes

- I found [jestpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jestpack), but I don't want to use it as it requires Node >= 5, and I want to use Node 4.2.3. It also doesn't work with Jest >= 0.8, and I want to use Jest 0.8, as it's currently the latest and I assume has the best chance of being in sync with the live docs and react version (0.14.6).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm doing that's working for me.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-jest
npm install --save-dev coffee-react
```

In `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/jest-script-preprocessor",
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
        "<rootDir>/node_modules/."
    ],
    "testFileExtensions": ["coffee", "cjsx", "js", "jsx"],
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["coffee", "cjsx", "js", "jsx"]
}
```

Take note of the **`unmockedModulePathPatterns`**. I set it to match everything in `node_modules`. You might not want that, but if you start getting errors like `Error: Failed to get mock metadata:...`, consider it, as [recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33965690/jest-issue-reactelement-js-failed-to-get-mock-metadata).

In `jest-script-preprocessor.js`:

```
var babelJest = require('babel-jest');
var coffee = require('coffee-react');

module.exports = {
    process: function(src, filename) {
        if (filename.indexOf('node_modules') === -1) {
            if (filename.match(/\.coffee|\.cjsx/)) {
                src = coffee.compile(src, {bare: true});
            } else {
                src = babelJest.process(src, filename);
            }
        }
        return src;
    }
};
```

Comment: It did not work for me, I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected token import" when running tests of jsx files.